# C# WPF - OpenTK GLControl mouse events

Tags: c#, wpf, opentk

I have a WPF project setup using an OpenTK GLControl inside of a Windows Forms Host... When I tie events to the GLControl's Mouse events (MouseDown, MouseWheel, etc) I cannot get them to function. Any mouse input done while the mouse is over the GLControl never seems to fire. Is there a way to accomplish mouse inputs over a GLControl that is inside of a Forms Host?

I tie the event when the GLControl is loaded using

```
glControl1.MouseWheel += glControl1_MouseWheel;
```

and then create

```
private void glControl1_MouseWheel(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Do something");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In you proyect add an user control, then in the .cs, you have something similar to:

```
public partial class WindowGL: System.Windows.Forms.UserControl{

private void mouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e){}
private void mouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e){}
private void mouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e){}
}
```

then in design view into properties connect the event with the function.
And in the WPF:

```
this.diagramHost.Child = new WindowGL();
```

See: https://kishordgupta.wordpress.com/2010/12/21/opentk-a-simple-2d-clock-design-in-windows-form-c-basic-opentk-1/